# Copy data from one column to other column (which is in a different table)

Tags: sql

I want to copy data from one column to another column of other table. How can I do that?

I tried the following:

```
Update tblindiantime Set CountryName =(Select contacts.BusinessCountry From contacts)
```

but it did not work.

I want to copy "BusinessCountry" column of contact table to "CountryName" column of tblindiantime table.

Comment: To copy columns from one table to another, you need some kind of relation between the tables. Do the two tables have a common ID?

Comment: Which database and version are you using?

Answer (score 103, accepted):

In SQL Server 2008 you can use a multi-table update as follows:

```
UPDATE tblindiantime 
SET tblindiantime.CountryName = contacts.BusinessCountry
FROM tblindiantime 
JOIN contacts
ON -- join condition here
```

You need a join condition to specify which row should be updated.

If the target table is currently empty then you should use an INSERT instead:

```
INSERT INTO tblindiantime (CountryName)
SELECT BusinessCountry FROM contacts
```

Comment: Hi thankx for ur rep but it is showing me following error
Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'IndianTime', table 'tqms.dbo.tblindiantime'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
The statement has been terminated.

Comment: @AmitPatil - I know this is old but may help someone like you.
Use ISNULL(contacts.BusinessCountry, '') instead of just contacts.BusinessCountry and it should solve your problem.
We are basically replacing null with a empty string.

Comment: Because this example doesn't show what a "join condition" might be, also see Michael Pakhantsov's answer, and [cedrikdlb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25674132/199364), and [Parveen's answer to a similar question, where two columns must be compared to pick the correct row](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17350703/199364).

Answer (score 194):

**Here the query:**

Same Table:

```
UPDATE table_name 
SET column1 = column2
```

Different Table:

```
UPDATE table_name1 
    SET column1 = (
        SELECT column2
        FROM table_name2
        WHERE table_name1.id = table_name2.id
    );
```

Comment: Is wrong in the context of the question, where asker specifically involves 2 tables.

Comment: Its working for mysql in case of columns are relates to same table.

Comment: This does however solve my problem, and I got here through the question title which probably matches this answer more than it matches the detail in the question!

Comment: This answer answers the title of the question, rather than the question itself. Still, I found this useful for what I was trying to do.

Comment: this is an excellent answer; it helped me to copy only one column from my backup to the main table!

Comment: I don't understand how does it update all columns in the table. Because the subquery returns multiple rows and there is no where condition.

Comment: this is worked for me .... 

UPDATE table_name1 
    SET column1 = (
        SELECT column2
        FROM table_name2
        WHERE table_name1.id = table_name2.id
    );

thank you

Answer (score 28):

**Table2.Column2 => Table1.Column1**

I realize this question is old but the accepted answer did not work for me. For future googlers, this is what worked for me:

```
UPDATE table1 
    SET column1 = (
        SELECT column2
        FROM table2
        WHERE table2.id = table1.id
    );
```

Whereby:

- table1  = table that has the column that needs to be updated
- table2  = table that has the column with the data
- column1 = blank column that needs the data from column2 (this is in table1)
- column2 = column that has the data (that is in table2)

Comment: Worked for me - but is same as above answer by `[Michael Pakhantsov]`

Comment: You are right, @mmcra, that it is now the same as the answer above. However, it was not the same at the time that I had written this comment. You will notice that it was edited in Sept and the errors were fixed. I had written this comment in June.

Answer (score 16):

Hope you have key field is two tables.

```
 UPDATE tblindiantime t
   SET CountryName = (SELECT c.BusinessCountry 
                     FROM contacts c WHERE c.Key = t.Key 
                     )
```

Comment: this is valid only if you replace one field by one other field it will throw `ORA-01427: single-row subquery returns more than one row` if the select return more than one row, what if I want to select more than one row and update the column with these values?

Comment: @Muhammad Ramahy, Do you have nested table in update column? in subquery return several rows, then Key is not PrimaryKey for contacts table. If you have composite primary key you just need conditions to WHERE clause.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with "Hope you have key field is two tables"

Comment: @Krige - He apparently means *"If the two tables have a shared Key field to identify which row of each table matches the row of other table"*. If you don't, then you need to change what is after `WHERE`. For example, if tblindiantime has field `ContactID`, which is the `ID` of the row in `contacts` which belongs with each row in tblindiantime, then you would use `WHERE tblindiantime.ContactID=contacts.ID`. See [cedrikdlb's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25674132/199364) for another variation.

Answer (score 10):

[A similar question's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17350703/1399315) worked more correctly for me than [this question's selected answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3361804/1399315) (by Mark Byers).  Using Mark's answer, my updated column got the same value in all the rows (perhaps the value from the first row that matched the join).  Using ParveenaArora's answer from the other thread updated the column with the correct values.

Transforming Parveena's solution to use this question' table and column names, the query would be as follows (where I assume the tables are related through tblindiantime.contact_id):

```
UPDATE tblindiantime
SET CountryName = contacts.BusinessCountry
FROM contacts
WHERE tblindiantime.contact_id = contacts.id;
```

Answer (score 3):

I think that all previous answers are correct, this below code is very valid specially if you have to update multiple rows at once, note: it's PL/SQL

```
DECLARE
    CURSOR myCursor IS 
      Select contacts.BusinessCountry 
      From contacts c WHERE c.Key = t.Key;
    ---------------------------------------------------------------------
BEGIN
    FOR resultValue IN myCursor LOOP
        Update tblindiantime t
        Set CountryName=resultValue.BusinessCountry 
        where t.key=resultValue.key;
    END LOOP;
END;
```

I wish this could help.

Answer (score 2):

Now it's more easy with management studio 2016.

Using SQL Server Management Studio

To copy data from one table to another

1.Open the table with columns you want to copy and the one you want to copy into by right-clicking the tables, and then clicking **Design**.

2.Click the tab for the table with the columns you want to copy and select those columns.

3.From the **Edit** menu, click **Copy**.

4.Open a new Query Editor window.

5.Right-click the Query Editor, and then click **Design Query in Editor**.

6.In the **Add Table** dialog box, select the source and destination table, click **Add**, and then close the **Add Table** dialog box.

7.Right-click an open area of the the Query Editor, point to **Change Type**, and then click **Insert Results**.

8.In the **Choose Target Table for Insert Results** dialog box, select the destination table.

9.In the upper portion of the Query Designer, click the source column in the source table.

10.The Query Designer has now created an INSERT query. Click OK to place the query into the original Query Editor window.

11.Execute the query to insert the data from the source table to the destination table.

For More Information https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/tables/copy-columns-from-one-table-to-another-database-engine

Answer (score 1):

It can be solved by using different attribute.

- Use the cell Control click event.
- Select the column value that your transpose to anther column.
- send the selected value to the another text box or level whatever you fill convenient and a complementary button to modify the selected property.
- update the whole stack op the database and make a algorithm with sql query to overcome this one to transpose it into the another column.

Answer (score 0):

In my case using MySQL the following query for copying between different tables was **not** working, as I was getting error `Subquery returns more than 1 row`.

```
UPDATE table1 
SET column1 = (
    SELECT column2
    FROM table2
    WHERE table2.id = table1.id
);
```

What worked was the answer from https://stackoverflow.com/a/38250260, which also allows to update multiple columns.

```
UPDATE table1 a JOIN table2 b 
ON a.id = b.id 
SET 
a.column1 = b.column2,
a.column1a = b.column2a,
a.column1b = b.column2b
```