# Subquery returns more than 1 row with update

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have been wrestling this issue for hours to no avail. I've been looking at many of the stackoverflow.com questions related to subqueries returning more than one row, but have not been able to find one that helps in my case.

I have two tables: **clients** and **positions**. I am trying to UPDATE **positions.client_id** with **clients.id** WHERE **clients.file_name** = **positions.file_name**.

Basically I have a list of positions that need to be assigned to clients. Every client has multiple positions, but every position is assigned to exactly one client. In other words, **client_id** is not unique in **positions**, but **id** is unique (primary key) in **clients**.

Here's what I have been trying different variations with:

```
UPDATE positions 
SET client_id = (SELECT clients.id 
FROM clients 
WHERE clients.file_name = positions.file_name)
```

It returns.

> ## 1242 - Subquery returns more than 1 row

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: the advice to use `LIMIT` will offer no guarantees. first try running `SELECT DISTINCT id from clients where file_name = '<<filename>>'` in order to make sure that you have a 1..1 relationship between clients and file names.

Comment: or `SELECT file_name, COUNT(DISTINCT id) FROM clients GROUP BY file_name` to get a more complete picture.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the [LIMIT clause](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/limit-optimization.html). This will limit the amount of results to one row.

```
UPDATE positions 
SET client_id =
    (
     SELECT clients.id 
     FROM clients 
     WHERE clients.file_name = positions.file_name
     LIMIT 1
    )
```

Keep in mind that the best practice is typically NOT to use subqueries to achieve what you want in SQL.

Comment: @Tomanow it may have worked but how can you be sure the 1 row you are returning is the right row?

Comment: @Zane, this is true. This assumes that there is a unique index placed on the file_name column.

Comment: As @Zane says, the limit is the wrong thing to use. Instead you could give it a shot with a `distinct` in the subquery

Comment: So what if I have to Update more than 1 Row

Answer (score 4):

if you have a more than rows, you can use like this

```
UPDATE table1 a JOIN table2 b 
ON a.field1 = b.field1 
SET 
a.field2 = b.field2,
a.field3 = b.field3,
a.field4 = b.field4
```

Another way

```
UPDATE table1 a JOIN table2 b 
ON a.field1 = b.field1 
SET 
a.field2 = b.field2,
a.field3 = b.field3,
a.field4 = b.field4
```