# ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row

Tags: sql, proc

```
proc sql; 
update tableA
set tableA.measure=(select tableB.measure_id from TableB)
where tablA.CD=(select TableB.CD from TableB);
quit;
```

WARNING: Character expression will be truncated when assigned to character column Measure.
ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row.

Could you please help

Comment: There’s no WHERE clauses on your TableB subqueries, so they will return every row in that table.    This causes the error.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Subquery returns more than 1 row with update](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14631814/subquery-returns-more-than-1-row-with-update)

Comment: proc sql; 
update tableA
set tableA.measure=(select tableB.measure_id from TableB
where tablA.CD= TableB.CD from TableB);
quit; I tried this using the link provided it gave me the same error

Comment: proc sql; 
update s
set measu=(select measu_id from value._VALUESETS as n
where coden=s.CD);
quit; */;

Comment: I tried the above code and i got this ERROR: Subquery evaluated to more than one row.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might mean:

```
proc sql; 

UPDATE 
    tableA
SET 
    measure = tableB.measure_id
FROM 
    tableA
    JOIN tableB ON tablA.CD=TableB.CD;

quit;
```

Comment: how do we use the = when we have libname.tablename.columnname like below. proc sql; 

UPDATE 
    tableA
SET 
    measure = libname.tableB.measure_id
FROM 
    tableA
    JOIN tableB ON tablA.CD=TableB.CD

quit; when i tried this im getting error "ERROR 22-322: Syntax error, expecting one of the following: ;, !!, *, **, +, ',', -, /, WHERE, ||.  
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored."

Comment: Sorry - I hadn't put a semi-colon at the end of the SQL statement. I've added it now. Please try again

Comment: this still didnt work

Comment: Is it still the same error message?

Comment: Please show the results of the following query:.   SELECT
   tableA.CD,
   COUNT( measure) nul
FROM 
    tableA
 JOIN tableB 
ON tablA.CD=TableB.CD
GROUP BY tableA.CD
HAVING COUNT(measure) > 1;

Comment: this are the results Z6820 3
Z6821 3
Z6822 3
Z6823 3
Z6824 3

Comment: So when you update with a join on CD which of the 3 values of measure do you want to use? MIN() MAX() AVG() ?