# PostgreSQL - copy column from related table

Tags: sql, postgresql

So I have three tables: companies, addresses and company_address.

For optimization reasons I need to copy `city` column from `addresses` table to `companies` table. Relation between companies and addresses is many to one (as many companies can occupy same address). They are connected through company_address table, consisting of `address_id` and `company_id` columns.

I found this solution for case without intermediate table: [How to copy one column of a table into another table's column in PostgreSQL comparing same ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17333994/how-to-copy-one-column-of-a-table-into-another-tables-column-in-postgresql-comp)

Trying to modify query I came up with:

```
UPDATE company SET company.city=foo.city
FROM (
    SELECT company_address.company_id, company_address.address_id, address.city 
    FROM address LEFT JOIN company_address 
    ON address.id=company_address.address_id
) foo
WHERE company.id=foo.company_id;
```

but it gives error:

> ERROR: column "company" of relation "company" does not exist

I cant figure out what is going on. I'll be grateful for any ideas.

Comment: `UPDATE company SET company.city=foo.city` ==>> `UPDATE company SET city=foo.city` (and you don't need the subquery)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need a subquery for that. Also, refer in the `SET` clause to your table columns without preceding with table name.

I believe that since your `WHERE` condition includes joined table, it should be `INNER JOIN` instead of a `LEFT JOIN`.

```
UPDATE company c
SET city = a.city
FROM address a
INNER JOIN company_address ca ON a.id = ca.address_id
WHERE c.id = ca.company_id
```

Note how using aliases for table names shortens the code and makes it readable at the very first glance.

Answer (score 0):

You're right syntactically, you just don't need the table name at the beginning of the update statement:

```
UPDATE company SET city=foo.city
FROM (
SELECT company_address.company_id, company_address.address_id, address.city 
FROM address LEFT JOIN company_address 
ON address.id=company_address.address_id
) foo
WHERE company.id=foo.company_id;
```