# Want to copy one column data into anothers table column in SQL...using this query its not working

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-update

```
UPDATE temp_test
 SET country_i = (select a.country_code from temp_test2 a,temp_test c
                       where c.country_i is null and 
            a.active = 'A' and c.created_by = a.partner_by)
```

Comment: here is answer to your question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361768/how-to-copy-data-from-one-column-to-other-column

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a **MERGE** statement. It is easy to understand.

```
MERGE INTO temp_test t
USING temp_test2 u
ON (t.created_by = u.partner_by)
WHEN MATCHED THEN 
UPDATE SET
   t.country_i = u.country_code
   WHERE t.country_i IS NULL
   AND   u.active = 'A';
```

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE temp_test c SET country_i = (select a.country_code from temp_test2 a where a.active = 'A' and c.created_by = a.partner_by) where c.country_i is null;
```

In my mind it should work...