# Take a value from an SQL table cell and insert it in another cell

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-update

I have an old SQL database (Microsoft's SQL Server) with thousands of rows that contains data as follows:

```
ID      urlString

1      page.aspx?pageID=34
2      page.aspx?pageID=163
3      page.aspx
4      page.aspx?pageID=23
```

I've added a new column (pageID) to the database. I want to create an UPDATE query to copy the pageID from the URLstring and insert it in the new column (pageID) as follows. If there is no pageID I want to add 0. How can I accomplish that?

```
ID      URLstring                pageID

1      page.aspx?pageID=34        34
2      page.aspx?pageID=163       163
3      page.aspx                  0
4      page.aspx?pageID=23        23
```

Comment: What DB engine do you use?

Comment: what rdbms are you working with? string manipulation functions usually have different formats in different databases.

Comment: Microsoft's SQL Server

Comment: Can PageId be followed with other query string values? (I mean, can the url be `page.aspx?pageID=34&something=value`)?

Comment: No but it could be page.aspx?something=value&pageID=34. pageID is always the last.

Answer (score 0):

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET pageID= 
SUBSTRING(urlString,CHARINDEX('=', urlString)+1,CHARINDEX('=', urlString))
```

To have the 0 value

```
UPDATE YourTable
SET pageID= 
CASE 
        WHEN CHARINDEX('=', urlString) > 0 THEN 
            SUBSTRING(urlString,CHARINDEX('=', urlString)+1,CHARINDEX('=', urlString))
        ELSE 0
    END
```

Comment: it'll set final value to newcoulmn

Answer (score 0):

```
I try it:

update yourtable
set pageID=
case when
substring(URLstring, charindex('=', URLstring) +1, len(URLstring) -  charindex('=', URLstring)    )
=URLstring then '0'
else 
substring(URLstring, charindex('=', URLstring) +1, len(URLstring) -  charindex('=', URLstring)    )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

please try the following

```
SELECT urlString,  cast(REVERSE(SUBSTRING(REVERSE(urlString),0,CHARINDEX('=',REVERSE(urlString)))) as smallint) AS [pageID]
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Well, whichever SQL language variant the database uses will make a difference here. (i.e. SQLplus, NOSQL, etc.) However, it shouldn't be toooooooooo complicated. Assuming that both columns are INTs, you could probably just do something like so

```
UPDATE table_name
SET pageID = URLstring;
```

Here is some other sources for additional information.

A similar stack overflow question:
[Copy data from one column to other column (which is in a different table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361768/copy-data-from-one-column-to-other-column)

This is a TutorialsPoint webpage on the matter: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sql/sql-update-query.htm (TutorialsPoint is usually one of my first stops for any programming-related knowledge, it's quite a valuable website.)

This is a w3schools webpage on the matter: http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp

Hope you get everything figured out!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by the [`PARSENAME`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188006.aspx) using the following `UPDATE` query:

```
UPDATE TestTable 
SET pageID = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(REPLACE(URLstring, '=', '.'), 1)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(URLstring, '=', '.'), 1)
            ELSE 0 END
```

Sample execution with the given sample data

```
DECLARE @TestTable TABLE (ID INT, URLstring VARCHAR (200), PageID INT);

INSERT INTO @TestTable (ID, URLstring, pageID) VALUES
(1, 'page.aspx?pageID=34'  , NULL ),
(2, 'page.aspx?pageID=163' , NULL ),
(3, 'page.aspx'            , NULL ),
(4, 'page.aspx?pageID=23'  , NULL );

UPDATE @TestTable 
SET pageID = CASE WHEN ISNUMERIC(PARSENAME(REPLACE(URLstring, '=', '.'), 1)) = 1 THEN PARSENAME(REPLACE(URLstring, '=', '.'), 1)
            ELSE 0 END
```

So the `SELECT * FROM @TestTable` will result as:

```
ID  URLstring              PageID
------------------------------------
1   page.aspx?pageID=34    34
2   page.aspx?pageID=163   163
3   page.aspx              0
4   page.aspx?pageID=23    23
```

Comment: this will fail if the query string contains more then 4 parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Using [`CASE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx), [`PATINDEX`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx) and [`SUBSTRING`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187748.aspx) it's fairly easy to extract the page id from the url.

Create and populate sample table (**Please** save us this step in your future questions)

```
DECLARE @T As TABLE 
(
    Id int IDENTITY(1,1), 
    URLString varchar (40), 
    PageId int
)

INSERT INTO @T (URLString) VALUES
('page.aspx?blabla=yadayada&pageID=34'),
('page.aspx?pageID=163'),
('page.aspx'),
('page.aspx?pageID=23')
```

Update statement:

```
UPDATE @T
SET PageId =    CAST(
                    CASE WHEN PATINDEX('%pageID=%', URLString) > 0 THEN
                        SUBSTRING(URLString, PATINDEX('%pageID=%', URLString) + 7, LEN(URLString))
                    ELSE
                        '0'
                    END
                 As int)
```

Verification:

```
SELECT Id, URLString, PageId 
FROM @T
```

Results:

```
Id          URLString                                PageId
----------- ---------------------------------------- -----------
1           page.aspx?blabla=yadayada&pageID=34      34
2           page.aspx?pageID=163                     163
3           page.aspx                                0
4           page.aspx?pageID=23                      23
```