# SQL: Copy data from one table into another using unique key present in both tables

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables that contain the same unique key. I need to match those keys and then copy data from table 2 into table 1

Original:

```
Key COL1 COL2          Key COL3
 1   01  NULL           1   05
 2   02  NULL           2   12
 3   03  NULL           3   27
```

Required:

```
Key COL1 COL2          Key COL3
 1   01   05            1   05
 2   02   12            2   12
 3   03   27            3   27
```

Thank you for the help.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Comment: Kindly refer the below post
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361768/copy-data-from-one-column-to-other-column.

Comment: I'm using Microsoft SSMS

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your best answer is probably an `UPDATE` `FROM` a lookup based on the two tables (for SQL Server, some say use `JOIN`, some say there's no need, and without the `join` is more concise).

See some examples here: [SQL update from one Table to another based on a ID match](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/224732/sql-update-from-one-table-to-another-based-on-a-id-match)

For convenience, here's a query adapted for your scenario:

```
UPDATE Table1 SET 
    Col1 = Table2.Col1,
    Col2 = Table2.Col2,
    Col3 = Table2.Col3,
FROM Table2
WHERE Table2.Key = Table1.Key
```

Comment: Thank you for the example link it led me in the right direction.

Comment: UPDATE table2 
    SET table2.col1 = table1.col1, 
     table2.col2 = table1.col2,FROM table1, table2 
WHERE table1.memberid = table2.memberid

Comment: Hopefully someone can take edit my bad responses since I can't yet.

Answer (score 0):

TRY this:

`update table1
  set col2 = (
               select col3
                 from table2 
                where table2.key=table1.key
              )
 where exists (
               select * 
                 from table2 
                where table2.key=table1.key
              );`

Comment: Can you explain your answer instead of just dumping code in here? That way people can learn from it.

Comment: Use update statement by setting the value in table2 from table1 by filtering using keys from both tables. Or you can use join also to get the same result.