# SQL Server - Update a whole column using Order By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm using SQL Server and have Management Studio installed if this is relevant.

I would like to copy a whole column from one table to another, but the catch is that the table I must copy to needs to be ordered a certain way, as there is no common identity between these tables I could use to join them.

I have read these two questions:

- [Copy data from one column to other column (which is in a different table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3361768/copy-data-from-one-column-to-other-column-which-is-in-a-different-table)
- [SQL Server: UPDATE a table by using ORDER BY](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3439110/sql-server-update-a-table-by-using-order-by)

and I tried to combine their answers as follows:

```
WITH cte AS
(
    -- I must specify TOP to use ORDER BY
    SELECT TOP(50000) *
    FROM TableToCopyTo
    ORDER BY ColumnUsedToOrder
)
UPDATE cte 
SET ColumnToCopyTo = (SELECT ColumnToCopyFrom FROM TableToCopyFrom)
```

When I try to execute this query, it returns the following error:

> Msg 512, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
>   Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.

I've tried looking up the error but couldn't find relevant information.

I would like to either understand why my query is wrong or find an alternative to achieve what I'm looking for.

Comment: The error message says it all... The UPDATE wants one value at the time, not a whole bunch.

Comment: Take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/982919/sql-update-query-using-joins

Comment: @jarlh, I tried replacing the Update part with a "SELECT * FROM cte" and it indeed worked. That's unfortunate, I thought I could use an Update on this one.

Comment: Btw, your username doesn't match your profile picture. Loki is the father of Jörmungandr.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following answer. You have to give the matching columns for the two tables.

```
;WITH cte AS
(
-- I must specify TOP to use ORDER BY
SELECT TOP(50000) *
FROM TableToCopyTo
ORDER BY ColumnUsedToOrder
)
UPDATE cte SET ColumnToCopyTo = ColumnToCopyFrom
FROM cte
JOIN TableToCopyFrom A
ON cte.ColumnName = A.EquvaliantColumnName
```

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: @marc_s, Now its fine? Thanks for the suggestion.

Comment: Much better now, yes! :-)

Answer (score 0):

Provided that your `TableToCopyFrom` has equal to or more rows than `TableToCopyTo` I'd use something like:

```
WITH cte1 AS
(
  -- I must specify TOP to use ORDER BY
  SELECT TOP(50000) *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ColumnUsedToOrder) AS RwNr
  FROM TableToCopyTo
  ORDER BY ColumnUsedToOrder
), cte2 AS (
  SELECT *
    , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (SELECT 1)) AS RwNr -- or order by a column you know makes sense; this way it'll order it the way the data "sits" in the table, but it's not guaranteed
  FROM TableToCopyFrom
)
UPDATE cte1
SET ColumnToCopyTo = ColumnToCopyFrom
FROM cte1
  INNER JOIN cte2 ON cte1.RwNr = cte2.RwNr;
```

**EDIT:**  please make sure you test this logic on some copy of the database first of course.

Answer (score 0):

you can  use Row number as key as follows

```
    WITH tblDest AS
    (

    SELECT Row_Number() over(order by ColumnUsedToOrder) as RowNum, TOP(50000) *
    FROM TableToCopyTo
    ORDER BY ColumnUsedToOrder
    ),tblSrc as
    (
    select  Row_Number() over(order by (select null)) as RowNum,ColumntoCopyFrom 
    from TableToCopyFrom
    )

   update tblDest set ColumntoCopyto = ColumntoCopyFrom  
   FROM tblDest join tblSrc on tblDest.RowNum = tblSrc.RowNum
```